# Apache ssl does not work remotely

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I am trying to setup apache2.2 with ssl, but I am having trouble to connect remotely to it.

```
My Virtualhost looks like this:
NameVirtualHost *:443
 <VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/host1/apache.pem

    ServerName mail.host1.net

    DocumentRoot /usr/share/squirrelmail
    <Directory />
            Options -Indexes
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mail.host1.log
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mail.host1-access.log combined

    ServerSignature Off
</VirtualHost>
```

I've created the ssl file using this tutorial:
http://wiki.debian.org/Self-Signed_Certificate

When I connect local

```
server ~ openssl s_client -connect localhost:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 /C=AU/ST=Some-State/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 /C=AU/ST=Some-State/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=AU/ST=Some-State/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
i:/C=AU/ST=Some-State/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[...]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=AU/ST=Some-State/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
issuer=/C=AU/ST=Some-State/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 1265 bytes and written 319 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 1024 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: [...]
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: [...]
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1357993878
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
---
closed
```

but when I do it remotely:

```
[13:27:05:gentoo@~/]openssl s_client -connect mail.host1.net:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
139720085706408:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 322 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

Nmap tells me that port 443 is open.

When I connect to my site via http://mail.host1.net:443 it works, but ssl doesn't

Hope someone can help.

The log says nothing but:

```
[Sat Jan 12 19:25:50 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Sat Jan 12 19:25:50 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need `SSLCertificateKeyFile` pointing to the private key.  But that doesn't explain why you'd get a working SSL connection to `localhost` - sounds like you might have bits of an older config still in place.

Did you fully restart Apache after making the SSL config changes?  Can you provide the output of `apachectl -S`?

Comment: You are almost right: SSLCertificateKeyFile is not required. Anyway. I had some misconfiguration in my apache configs. Apache directed my request to the wrong VirtualHost and so no SSL connection was possible. Thanks!